# AngularJS one service call at a time

Tags: angularjs, service

I have 2 AngularJs service calls suppose:

```
    angular service call 1;
    angular service call 2;
```

What I want is  call 1 complete and set some data in hidden fields, then call2 should trigger? I can't write call 2 in call 1's success because call 1 will not triggers every time.

Comment: Too vague to answer, but something like this anyway: `serviceCall1.then(function(data) { sendDataToHiddenFields(); return serviceCall2() })`

Answer (score 0):

If you want service.call2 to be called even if service.call1 failed, you can use `finally` :

```
Service.call1().then(function() {
    // Success handler
}, function() {
    // Error handler
}).finally(function() {
    // Always execute this on both error and success
    Service.call2()
});
```